# TestLink integration in Jenkins

Tags: php, testing, jenkins, testlink

can someone tell me, where the testng-results.xml is processed by TestLink?

I guess some explanation is required:
I've got a system build by using the jenkins-testlink [tutorial](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/753702/jenkins.pdf).
When I build the project in jenkins, TestLink somehow process the results to get them into the test execution dashboard. I would like to know in which funktion or file TestLink is doing this.

Answer (score 0):

this is done by testlink-jenkins plugin. After your build job is finished java plugin validate your testng-results.xml file and update the fields accordingly using API calls in testslink. Processing happens purely on jenkins side